# Where did David "sit before Hashem" in Divrei Hayamim I 17:16?

Tags: king-david, book-of-chronicles

In Divrei Hayamim I 17:16 we read:

"And King David came and sat before the L-rd, and he said, "Who am I, O L-rd G-d, and who is my house, that You have brought me thus far?

Reading this verse, the folllowing questions come to my mind:

1. It says that David came. Where did he come? Was it the tent where he stationed the Ark, perhaps?
2. " Sat before the L-rd" - does this mean that he got on his knees?

Answer (score 2):

The Metzudat David [says](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.17.16?lang=bi&with=Metzudat%20David&lang2=en) that he was right in front of the ark. By looking at the Talmud, Yoma [69b](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.17.16?lang=bi&p2=Steinsaltz_on_Yoma.69b.1&lang2=bi&w2=Tosafot&lang3=en) it seems that this was in the azarah. The only discussion I can see about "sitting" has to do with comparing it to the sitting one does when eating certain sacrifices (look at the tosafot on 25a) so I don't see that it was kneeling.